# In JavaScript, cannot document.getElementById is null even if the element is in the DOM

Tags: reactjs

In React, I am using a component, which has `<input type="text" id="location" />`. When the DOM loads the component, in the `componentDidMount()` of the component, I will try to search the element.

```
componentDidMount(){
    debugger;
    let ele = document.getElementById('location');
    console.log('ele', ele)
}
```

when it breaks at the `debugger`, I look at the DOM (Element tab in Chrome), the above input element is already there, but the `ele` is still null in console.

why? the element is already loaded into DOM, but I still cannot find it?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code  should work. But Why are you using jquery approach? `ReactDom.findNode` is for this. You can add `ref` to access the element.

```
componentDidMount(){
    debugger;
   var Value = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.location).value;
    console.log('ele', ele)
}

<input type="text" ref="location" />
```